# Appending iframe with correct url

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to load an iframe this is what I have done

```
document.getElementsByName('iFrameName')[0].src = url;
```

but it is appending the url of the file to the current url e.g.
[www.website.com/currentpage](http://www.website.com/currentpage)

so instead of the url to be [www.website.com/file.html](http://www.website.com/file.html)

it is now [www.website.com/currentpage/file.html](http://www.website.com/currentpage/file.html)

How can I go about what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with Jquery instead of javascript.  use the below code to set attributes in an iframe.

```
$('iframeName').attr('src', 'url');
```

if you want to load the iframe use the load method.

```
$('iframeId').load('currentPageUrl.html #iframeId');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the setAttribute function to set the 'src' attribute with its value;
Refernce [Set Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) also see the examples over there.

Element.setAttribute(name, value);